# how to remove/unload a button in actionscript 3 - flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i have a button and i am trying to unload it but i dont know how.

I add the child as follows : addChild(buttons);

I try to remove it by : removeChild(buttons);

but this does not work, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are adding the button only once? If you add it twice you might just be laying one over the other and when you remove one of them you wouldn't see a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably losing an instance of that button from your code, most likely because the button was temporarily defined in a function.

2 options create a global instance of the button.

or the add the instance of that button into a list

```
var list:Array = new Array(); //define a global array

var b1:Button = new Button () //I honestly don't remember the synthax for creating a button 
list.push(b1);
```

then when ever you want to remove the buttons from stage just do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++){
    removeChild(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd that that doesn't work but if it is just one button you can do it like this.

buttons.parent.removeChild(buttons);